# Google forms to google sheets to google doc - How to set date to display dd-mmm-yy in sheets and doc?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm fairly new to coding, and am trying to get my head around a problem for some work admin. I´m hoping there's a quick and simple fix to this.

So as the title says, we enter info on a google form and then use the responses on sheets to complete a google doc (form). I need to set the date format to show as dd-mmm-yy, so that there is no confusion in a multinational team.

Here is my script so far (courtesy of a web tutorial - sorry can't remember where from)
[image]

Many thanks in advance for any help,

Chris

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)), like this:

```
  const timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(e.values[0]), 'GMT', 'd-MMM-yyyy');
```

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply! - maybe a daft question, but where do I need to insert this line of code?

Comment: Replace the `var timestamp` line with it. You can use `const` or `var` per your choice.